# uibutton title

Tags: iphone, uibutton

```
UIButton *ticketButtonObj=
    [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f 100.0f, 390.0f, 40.0f)];   
UIImage *buttonicon1=[UIImage alloc];
buttonicon1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Generalticket.png"];
```

how can set background of ticketButtonObj with buttonicon1 .. in left alignment ?

pls help me...  thanks and regards by raju.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: I'm guessing Objective-C, probably on a Mac or iPhone

Comment: @Raju - you've asked 24 questions and none of them have an accepted answer. Please review your questions and reward the people who've provided helpful answers - it's one of the things that keeps SO going forward.

Comment: you get 2 rep for everything you accept!

Answer (score 3):

```
UIButton *ticketButtonObj = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f 100.0f, 390.0f, 40.0f)];
UIImage* buttonicon1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Generalticket.png"];
[ticketButtonObj setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
ticketButtonObj.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

or, if you want to set the background image:

```
[ticketButtonObj setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But you cannot set the alignment for the background.